# Latest DevStudio Errors with API Editors

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

we are running into a scenario (both with the latest drop and built from source) with devstudio when restarting eclipse. Initially, we are able to both import as well as define an API fine, both with the graphical editor as well as view source. When we restart eclipse, an exception is displayed (below). Any help greatly appreciated:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot activate read/write transaction in read-only transaction context
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.acquire(TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.activate(TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl.start(TransactionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.impl.WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.createTransaction(WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.EMFCommandOperation.createTransaction(EMFCommandOperation.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.AbstractEMFOperation.execute(AbstractEMFOperation.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.DefaultOperationHistory.execute(DefaultOperationHistory.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.impl.WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.doExecute(WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:219)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.AbstractMediatorFlowCompartmentEditPart.addInSequenceInputConnector(AbstractMediatorFlowCompartmentEditPart.java:76)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.AbstractMediatorFlowCompartmentEditPart.addChild(AbstractMediatorFlowCompartmentEditPart.java:135)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.edit.parts.MediatorFlowMediatorFlowCompartment2EditPart.addChild(MediatorFlowMediatorFlowCompartment2EditPart.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refreshChildren(AbstractEditPart.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.access$3(GraphicalEditPart.java:1)

Comment: What is the exact version of Dev Studio you are trying out? Is it 3.2.0 or 3.3.0 alpha 2

Comment: this is using 3.3.0 alpha2. Initially, even on import, it will render correctly in the graphical editor. Once eclipse is restarted, it shows this error every time.

Comment: Thanks for reporting.. We will test this and let you know.

Comment: We were able to reproduce this problem with the DevS RESt API editor and we have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this problem in the latest Developer Studio 3.5.0 Alpha 4 version. Please download it from [1] and try the same scenario with the new version.

Thanks a lot for reporting the issue to us. It helps us to improve the editor a lot!!

[1]. http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/3.5.0/Alpha4/

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana